# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method saveData(view)

Tags: java, android

I've been having a problem with my app. While I was launching the app, it made me this error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.giuse.secondly, PID: 11553
              java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method saveDate(View) in the activity class com.example.giuse.secondly.NewSheet for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'button_save'
                  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4008)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4781)
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19874)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:902)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:697)
               Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: saveDate [class android.view.View]
                  at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:664)
                  at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:643)
                  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4001)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4781) 
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19874) 
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:902) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:697)
```

When I press the button SAVE, in the xml file called add_new_sheet.xml, it should save the data that I inserted it.

```
            <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/save_data"
        android:id="@+id/button_save"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:background="#444444"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:onClick="saveDate"
        tools:text="Save"
            tools:ignore="ObsoleteLayoutParam" />
```

The IDE suggest me of create onClick Listener. The IDE suggest me of create a onClick Listener.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be doing something wrong.First, it can be typo error check the name of method you made in your class

Second, make you your method must look like this

```
public void saveDate(View view){
//TODO: Add method functions here
}
```

You must have `View` as a parameter of your method

Comment: Thanks, I missed just that. I changed the class, but now I've another problem:
'code' E/SQLiteLog: (1) table geophysics_table has no column named municipality

Comment: it would be better if you ask new question for this with complete code

Answer (score 1):

Change `saveDate` in your XML `onClick` attribute to `saveData`. I assume that was a typo.

Answer (score 0):

Intead of setting onClick listener in xml, try to find a view of your button in your code and call a setOnClickListener and put there your implementation.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void addNewSheet (View view) { HashMap<String, String> queryValuesMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

in the "HashMap();" the words "String" are of gray color.